# ActivityTestRule is deprecated on android test

Tags: android, automated-tests, junit4, android-instrumentation, deprecation-warning

This is a scope of my instrumented test:

```kotlin
...
import androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class InstrumentDialogFragmentTest {

    @get:Rule
    val activityRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)
}
```

My gradle:

```
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
```

I'm getting this warning:

```
'ActivityTestRule<T : Activity!>' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java
```

Comment: I have hit the same issue. In [developers.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule#public-methods) link it states: This class is deprecated.
use ActivityScenario or ActivityScenarioRule instead. They offer a simpler, and safer way of controlling Activity lifecycles. There are then some hints for the conversion.
Sorry, I have not had time to attempt the conversion, so I do not know how involved the conversion is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can still use it on `'androidx.test:rules:1.2.0'`.
It is deprecated on `1.4.0`.
Use `ActivityScenario` or `ActivityScenarioRule` instead.

Learn more about `ActivityTestRule`: [developer.android](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/rule/ActivityTestRule)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
@get:Rule val testRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java, true, false)

...

testRule.launchActivity(intent)
```

To this:

```
launchActivity<MainActivity>(intent)
```

Here a good article about AndroidX testing: [click](https://medium.com/stepstone-tech/better-tests-with-androidxs-activityscenario-in-kotlin-part-1-6a6376b713ea)